# How to allocate a slice of floats in Go?

Tags: go

I'm learning `Go` programming and try to test the following `average` function:

```
func average(xs []float64) float64 {
    total := 0.0
    for _, v := range xs {
        total += v
    }
    return total / float64(len(xs))
}
```

I tried to generate a slice of random float numbers by:

```
var xs []float64
for n := 0; n < 10; n++ {
    xs[n] = rand.Float64()
}
```

however, I got

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

Question:

1. How to generate a slice of random number in Golang?
2. Is expression or function call, like `xs := []float64 { for ... }` allowed in slice literals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your method of generating the random numbers is fine, however `xs` is empty, and Go doesn't automatically extend slices. You could use [append](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices), however since you know the size in advance, it's most efficient to replace

```
var xs []float64
```

with

```
xs := make([]float64, 10)
```

which will give it the right size initially.

Answer (score 5):

@hobbs answered the part about your error, but still your solution will give you the same array every time you run it because you are not passing a random seed. I would do something like this:

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    s := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r := rand.New(s)

    xn := make([]float64, 10)

    for n := 0; n < 10; n++ {
        xn[n] = r.Float64()
    }

    fmt.Println(xn)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use the `rand` package - it's quite useful.